# Why does my trigger not want to send the e-mail

Tags: sql-server

Good day,

I am new to SQL and creating triggers and I have read up on it and just created a test trigger so as to gain a understanding of how to create one. 
I wrote the following Test Trigger and when debugging it, it went through successfully.

```
USE [Martin_test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Test_to_write_a_trigger]
ON [dbo].[_rtblAgents]
AFTER DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'ChamgeContactMail',
    @recipients = 'martin@aboutit.co.za',
    @body = 'Someone changed the customer',
    @subject = 'Change Customer';
END
```

However, when I make a change in the specified table, I get the following error.

[image]

The SQL Server is residing on my local machine.

Please could someone assist me.

Comment: Thats a really nice error message that tells you exactly what the problem is *and* how to fix it.  What's the problem?

Comment: Please, do not send mail (or do anything, which leaves current database or requires administrative rights) in triggers - you may result in various errors (like you already know) or timeouts or similar problems. You can build 'events queue' and process it in some scheduled job.